# Reference Type and Object Type Changing Java

Tags: java, object, reference

Given:

```
public class X implements Z {

    public String toString() { return "I am X"; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Y myY = new Y();
        X myX = myY;
        Z myZ = myX;
        System.out.println(myZ);
    }
}

class Y extends X {

    public String toString() { return "I am Y"; }
}

interface Z {}
```

What is the reference type of myZ and what is the type of the object it references?

A. Reference type is Z; object type is Z.

B. Reference type is Y; object type is Y.

C. Reference type is Z; object type is Y.

D. Reference type is X; object type is Z.

In this situation, I know that the object type is for sure Y, because I can test it with the .getClass() method. But I'm unsure of how to check what the reference type is. I'm assuming it is Z but that assumption is based on gut feeling and not logic.

Can anyone elaborate on what the reference type might be and why?

Thank you.

Comment: I would go with C, the object was create with new Y(); and myZ is declared as Z

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the object reference is defined statically at the point of its declaration:

```
Z myZ = ...
```

Therefore, the type of the reference is `Z`, so "C" should be the right answer.

Comment: what is the meaning of `reference type` overall? Why do we need it?

Comment: The reference declares the interface of the object. if type X had methods getA(), getB() and getC(). And type Y only has getA() and getB(), then by changing the interface (reference type) from X to Y, you could only get access to getA() and getB() even though the object is of type X.

Answer (score 2):

The Object was created with `new Y();` so the object type is `Y`

`myZ` was declared as `Z` (`Z myZ = ...;`) so the reference type is `Z`

Hence, the right answer is **C**

Answer (score 0):

The object is referenced to Z type

```
Z myZ = myX;
```

but originally it was created as Y type,

```
Y myY = new Y();
```

Hence, ans is obviously C.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is confusing because of the wrong answer that is marked as the true one; I have also met it. The truth is as they say, the reference is of type Z and the object type is Y, so C is the correct answer.